# How to post comments/feed for a Facebook app page from an android Application?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was sucked at implementing the functionality to post comments/feeds on facebook app page. I implemented posting the comments on own wall i.e., user who logged to facebook via application. I gone through the developers.facebook.com site to know the process to post. But failed to apply all the url  process as i was unable to add the dummy site to App Domain. Please kindly share info regarding the issue **"How to post comments/feed for a Facebook app page from an android Application?"**

Comment: Are you looking for complete example about how to post status on facebook from your android application?

Comment: Hi Dipak,
Happy New Year dipak.
I gone through the examples provided by facebook and solved my posting issues.Now I am working on the window posting my app on requesting with friends. I am able to post the comments. window containing App image with app details like how facebook displays for app request.

I was looking to set my app image and i set all the details about app.
From examples provided, we need to provide the url belonging to facebook. But where should i upload the app image to facebook and get the url. Please share the steps to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about this.